# O que seria uma frunção assíncrona no javascript?

Tags: javascript, async, promises

Quais as diferenças que possuem as funções assíncronas e geralmente em quais situações são de grande utilidade?

Answer (score -2):

Uma função assíncrona em JavaScript é uma função que pode ser executada em segundo plano, enquanto o restante do código continua sendo executado. Essa função é usada para operações que podem levar algum tempo para serem concluídas, como chamadas de API.

A função assíncrona é definida usando a palavra-chave 'async' antes da declaração da função. Dentro da função assíncrona, é preciso usar a palavra-chave 'await' antes de uma expressão que retorna uma promessa (Promise) para aguardar sua conclusão antes de continuar a execução do código.

Segue um exemplo de função assíncrona em JavaScript que simula uma chamada de API e aguarda a resposta:

```
async function buscaDadosAPI() {
  try {
    const resposta = await fetch('https://exemplo.com/api/dados');
    const dados = await resposta.json();
    console.log(dados);
  } catch (erro) {
    console.error(erro);
  }
}

buscaDadosAPI();
```

Nesse exemplo, a função buscaDadosAPI é definida como assíncrona usando a palavra-chave 'async'. Dentro dela, usamos a função fetch para fazer uma chamada de API e aguardamos a resposta usando a palavra-chave 'await'. Depois, uso a função json() para converter a resposta em um objeto JavaScript e armazenamos na constante dados. Por fim, imprimir o objeto no console.

Também usei um bloco try...catch para lidar com quaisquer erros que possam ocorrer durante a execução da função.

Por fim, chamamo a função buscaDadosAPI para executá-la. Como a função é assíncrona, ela é executada em segundo plano, permitindo que o restante do código continue sendo executado enquanto aguarda a resposta da API. Quando a resposta é retornada, o código dentro da função then é executado.